# Best way to count unique element in a string in r

Tags: r, unique

I'm a still a beginner in R and I have a question!

I have data frame of 222.000 observations and I'm interesting by a specific column which name is id. The problem is  it can be further ids separate by a ',' in the same string and I want to count unique element in a each string (I mean in each string of the first data frame).
For example:

```
      id                       results

0000001,0000003                   2

0000002,0000002                   1

0010001,0001006,0010001           2
```

I have used the function 'str_split_fixed' to separate all id in the same string and I put the result in a new data frame(so know I have only 1 id by string or nothing in a string). The problem is that can be as many as 68 ',' so the new data frame is huge with 68columns and 220.000 observations and it take much time(15 secondes maybe). After a used a apply function to know all unique.

Does someone know a more efficient way or have an idea?

Finally, I used the following code:

```
sapply(id, function(x) 
           length(    # count items
             unique(   # that are unique
                scan(   # when arguments are presented to scan as text 
                      text=x, what="", sep =",",  # when separated by ","
                      quiet=TRUE)))  )
```

But there is a message error:

```
Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  argument 'text' incorrect 
6 textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") 
5 scan(text = x, what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE) 
4 unique(scan(text = x, what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)) 
3 FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2 lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) 
1 sapply(id, function(x) length(unique(scan(text = x, 
    what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE))))
```

My R version is:

```
 R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/C/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.0.0 plyr_1.8.3   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  tools_3.2.2   Rcpp_0.12.2   stringi_1.0-1
>
```

I've tried this: `Encoding(id) <- "UTF-8"`
But the result is:

```
Error in `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "UTF-8")
```

and the output of dput(id) is from this:

```
   [9987,] "2320212,2320230"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [9988,] "4530090,4530917"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [9989,] "8532412"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9990,] "4560292"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9991,] "4540375"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9992,] "3311324"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9993,] "4540030"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9994,] "9010000"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9995,] "2811810"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9996,] "3311000"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9997,] "4540030"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9998,] "4540215"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [9999,] "1541201"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [10000,] "2423810"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [ getOption("max.print") est atteint -- 90000 lignes omises ]
```

the ouput is huge so I post just the end and the first line:

```
 [9002,] "9460000"
```

and for `dput( head(data$id) )`:

```
"9460000,9433000", "9460000,9436000", "9460000,9437000", 
"9510000", "9510010", "9510030", "9510090", "9910000", "9910020", 
"9910040", "9910090", "D", "FIELD_NOT_FOUND", "I"), class = "factor")
```

Thanks in advance, Jef

Comment: The solution may not lie in creating a new data frame since the ids from row to row are not uniform. Are you sure you're only interested in the 'id' column? Try to put your question into an example with data that looks like what you're working with.

Comment: what do you mean when you say that ids from row to row are not uniform?

Comment: In one instance you defined (with code) an `id` object but now you have a `w`-object. PLEASE post code that can be copied into a running session and tested. In this instance, post output from `dput(w)`

Comment: That column was not a character vector, but rather a factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(id, function(x) 
           length(    # count items
             unique(   # that are unique
                scan(   # when arguments are presented to scan as text 
                      text=x, what="", sep =",",  # when separated by ","
                      quiet=TRUE)))  )
# --- result: first typed line is 'names' of the items, not the results.
    1 2,3,4   1,1 
    1     3     1
```

The argument `text=x` should allow `scan` to accept a character element of length-1 and break it into components at divisions of the separator argument value. These will get passed element-by-element to the anonymous function from the id vector(or row by row if it were coming from a dataframe).

Comment: what does it mean "text=x" please?

Comment: I have a error message with:"argument 'text' incorrect"

Comment: The `text argument to `scan` was added to its capacities in R version 2.14 or thereabouts. If your version does not accept that argument it suggests an extremely old installation. You should post and exact copy of the _entire_ error message and details about your installation.

Comment: Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  argument 'text' incorrect

Comment: I have downloaded R 3 months ago

Comment: This suggest a problem with encoding. If this is being done on the example you offered, then you could try `Encoding(id) <- "UTF-8"` (and re-attempt the operation. Still need more complete details about your installation. You should post the exact code being used, the error message, and the output of `sessionInfo()` as an edit to your question rather than using comments.

Comment: that means if I have an id with more than 1 character it won't work? Because my id have 7 characters

Comment: I don't understand. The `id`-example had three elements. Are you using the word "id" as a generic reference to the name of a variable?

Comment: I mean, id is the column of my data frame so with 222.000 observations. And in each observation there are strings which represent idsale (7 numbers) and which are separated by an  ","

Comment: If the error is coming something other than the `id` example you offered you must at least post something that helps clarify the discrepancy in results,  this might be output from `dput( head(dfrm_name$id) )`

Comment: @tssssddde It's not a character vector; it's a factor. You would need to convert to character with as.character first. You also probably need to figure out what is the right answer for cases where the scanned values are not numbers. (You still did not include the entire output from the dput.)